# How to make for models with ForeignKey (autocomplete_fields) multi-step choices in standard Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Question for Django 2.0 with Select2 on the box. How to make for models with `ForeignKey` (`autocomplete_fields`) multi-step choices in standard Django Admin?

My `tours` app is:

**tours/models.py**:

```
class Tours(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=None, default=None)
    resort = models.ForeignKey(Resorts, on_delete=None, null=True, default=None)
```

**tours/admin.py**:

```
@admin.register(Tours)
class ToursAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('country', 'resort',)
    autocomplete_fields = ('country', 'resort',)
```

And this is my `countries` app:

**countries/models.py**:

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Resorts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

**countries/admin.py**:

```
class ResortsInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Resorts

@admin.register(Countries) 
class CountriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
    search_fields = ('name',)
    inlines = [ResortsInlineAdmin,]

@admin.register(Resorts)
class ResortsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'country',)
    search_fields = ('name',)
```

Would be nice after choose value in `Country` field — leave in `Resort` field only values that relate to this `Country` (`inlines` option in `countries/admin.py`).

Similar [demo](http://webersoft.ru/lab/sqlcelect/) with PHP + jQuery.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. Wondering if I'll have to use django-select2 as a dependency to do that

Comment: @JLugao at this moment, I solve my question with add to `tours/admin.py`  extra_context with `Country` and `Resort` IDs and hardcoded admin template (add some jQuery code for change field and re-build array of IDs into them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is too simple, but I've many hours in Google.

First, added extra context to `tours/admin.py` ([`ModelAdmin.change_view()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view)):

```
# tours/admin.py

@admin.register(Tours)
class ToursAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('country', 'resort',)
    autocomplete_fields = ('country', 'resort',)

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['resort_to_country'] = Resorts.objects.all().values_list('pk', 'country_id')
        return super().change_view(
            request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,
        )
```

Next, improve `templates/admin/tours/add_form.html` with JavaScript, like this:

```
// on bottom, into <script></script> tag:

var resort_to_country = [
    {% for i in resort_to_country %}
        ['{{ i.country }}', {{ i.pk }}, '{{ i.name }}'],
    {% endfor %}
];

var resorts_select_field = django.jQuery('#id_resort');
var countries_select_field = django.jQuery('#id_country');

countries_select_field.on('change', function () {
    resorts_select_field.empty();
    resort_to_country.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item[0] === countries_select_field.find(':selected').text()) {
            resorts_select_field.append(django.jQuery('<option></option>').attr('value', item[1]).text(item[2]));
        }
    });
});
```

That's all.

Comment: do you have a git example of the complete code for this please? I'm in an incredibly similar situation but dont know how to update the html/where